# Почему я получаю ошибку Invalid Pointer и мусор в результатах?

Tags: c++, память, vector

Я выполняю простенькое задание вот тут: https://stepik.org/lesson/13025/step/15?auth=login&unit=4377

Известно, что на доске 8×8 можно расставить 8 ферзей так, чтобы они не били друг друга. Вам дана расстановка 8 ферзей на доске, определите, есть ли среди них пара бьющих друг друга.

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
  bool in_danger = false;
  vector <int> x(8), y(8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            cin >> x[i];
    }
        else {
            cin >> y[i];
    }  
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i+=2){
      if((x[i] == x[i+1] || y[i+1] == y[i+1]) || (abs(x[i] - y[i]) == abs(x[i+1] - y[i+1]))){
          in_danger = true;
      }
  }
  if(in_danger){
      cout << "YES";
  }else{
      cout << "NO";
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

И его выполнение вызывает ошибку:

```
*** Error in `./main': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002537860 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
[0x4ad787]
[0x4b3012]
[0x4006c6]
[0x496743]
[0x496b02]
[0x400eea]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00583000 r-xp 00000000 fe:01 525472                             /sandbox/main
00782000-0078b000 rw-p 00182000 fe:01 525472                             /sandbox/main
0078b000-00790000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02523000-02562000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f1f90573000-7f1f90574000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd2c44a000-7ffd2c46b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd2c548000-7ffd2c54b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd2c54b000-7ffd2c54d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Я попытался проверить, что записано в массивах:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    cout << x[i] << " " << y[i];
}
```

И получил следующее: 1 00 72 00 43 00 24 00 8, хотя сам вводил: 1 7 2 4 3 2 4 8

Почему так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Необходимо определить, может ли пара ферзей напасть на друг друга, если известны координаты 8 ферзей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068589/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3):

Забавно.

Вы объявляете вектора с 8 элементами:

```
vector <int> x(8), y(8);
```

После чего ничтоже сумняшеся работаете с 16 (!) элементами:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        cin >> x[i];
}
    else {
        cin >> y[i];
}
```

Потом - скромно выходите за границы только на 1 элемент (да, вы можете возразить, что `i` у вас только 6 и не более, но все равно - так писать не надо...)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i+=2){
    if((x[i] == x[i+1] ....
```

Все, undefined behavior. Увы. У вас, к счастью, приводящее к немедленному краху программы.

**Update**

Для тех, кто в танке - сдавайте...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector <int> x(8), y(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cin >> x[i] >> y[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        for(int j = i+1; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            if (x[i] == x[j] || y[i] == y[j] ||
                abs(x[i]-x[j]) == abs(y[i]-y[j]))
            {
                cout << "YES"; return 0;
            }
        }
     cout << "NO";
}
```

Comment: Я должен получить 8 пар координат x y, то есть всего 16, которые можно разбить на два массива. А введено всего 6, потому что после я и получаю ошибку

Comment: Ну правильно - вы пишете далеко за пределами выделенной памяти и получаете ошибку...

Comment: Добавлю - проверка, есть ли такая пара, у Вас построена странно, и работать не будет.

Comment: Подождите, вы ввели всего 8 чисел, или 8 пар чисел? Если 8 чисел - то вы же только что писали *введено всего 6* о парах. Всё, блин, задолбало намекать! Посмотрите наконец, как вы пишете - через один элемент, в x[0], y[1], x[2], y[3].  **Что вы записываете в x[1]?** Понятно наконец? i при записи делить пополам надо! А еще лучше - не растягивать одну сущность - координаты ферзя - на два вектора!

Comment: @Harry А и вправду зачем вы намекаете - пишите прямо и понятно что не правильно.

Comment: Ввёл 6 чисел, после получил ошибку. Должен получить 16 **чисел**. И если "Вы объявляете вектора с 8 элементами, после чего ничтоже сумняшеся работаете с 16 (!) элементами:" - это такой намёк на то, что у меня одна координата всегда пропускается, то пусть у меня на вопросе будет хоть -1488, но такая медвежья услуга мне не нужна

Comment: @Cerbo Чтоб человек тренировал головной мозг. Я написал всё, осталось только дописать правильное решение, чтоб просто сдать и не думать. Вы хотите, чтобы я это сделал? Впрочем, чем меньше будут уметь и знать молодые, тем дороже будут цениться на рынке труда старые :)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, работающий код выглядит так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    bool in_danger = false, horizontal, diagonal;
    vector <int> x(8), y(8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cin >> x[i];
        cin >> y[i];
    } 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < 8; j++){ 
            horizontal = (x[i] == x[j]) || (y[i] == y[j]);
            diagonal = abs(x[i] - x[j]) == abs(y[i] - y[j]);
            if (horizontal || diagonal) {
                in_danger = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (in_danger) {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: О! таки дошло :) Только вот ответом на ваш вопрос - *Почему так?* - не является...